# irritating: bc float expression leads to integer result

Tags: bc

I have been happily using bc for a few weeks. Now I need to do some simple calculations like `1.0+27.0/37.0*5.0`, which `bc` in interactive mode calculates as integer result. I tried this on two different linux boxes. Same result: `1` instead of `4.67`...

Can you suggest an explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really using `bc` for several weeks? By default `bc` computes on integer numbers. You may change it either by typing first:

```
scale=8
```

(or whatever number of digits you need).

Or by launching `bc` with:   `bc -l` which is often the most convenient way since it also loads some scientific functions.

Comment: Baruchel, thanks a lot for the quick answer. You're perfectly right. I just didn't see that in the man pages.